# найти в интернете компьютеры с похожими именами

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

дело в том что мне нужно подключится к удаленному ноутбуку через интернет по ssh  на котором ununtu  `sudo service ssh user@pc` но я не помню имя компьютера знаю только имя пользователя , 
можно ли как то в консоли прописать какую то команду что бы получить список пк с похожими именами

Comment: А прям бук доступен по белому ip и прям на том, порту который ты знаешь и авторизация через пароль разрешена?

Comment: через пароль разрешена а ip не знаю и он в спящем режиме крышка закрыта , по локлке доступа нет только через интернет

Comment: если он в спящем режиме то он вряд ли проснется от обращения по ssh. А имя компьютера, нигде кроме как на самом комьютере вообще не известно и по имени обратится нельзя, если конечно это имя не прописано в DNS. А если оно прописано в DNS то вам надо попасть на DNS сервер и посмотреть список всех зарегистрированных имен

Comment: еще не факт что у роутера стоит переадресация 22 порта на ваш ноут. по локалке это другое, но если через Интернет удаленно - должно быть настроена перенапровление 22 порта это учитывая, что роутер получил от провайдера статисеский адрес (можно DDNS, но не думаю, что он у вас он есть). лучший способ удаленно подлючиться к станции - TeamViewer

Comment: @Mike WOL сейчас чуть ли не штатная фича всех сетевых карт. Другое дело, что ближайший маршрутизатор должен это уметь анонсировать.

Comment: @0andriy Только WOL обычно будит комп _специальным пакетом_, а отнюдь не tcp пакетом соединения на 22 порт. В принципе можно настоить на любую активность но тогда комп подключенный непосредственно к интернету будет просыпаться по нескольку раз в минуту :)

Comment: @Mike, именно об этом моё второе предложение.